# É possível ter acesso ao acumulador da transformada de hough usando opencv?

Tags: c++, processamento-de-imagens, opencv

Estou com esse pequeno prolema, procurei bastante na internet e na documentação mas não achei nada relacionado, preciso saber qual o valor de acumulação de cada circulo gerado pela função, exemplo:
circulo de centro (x,y) raio r teve 50 pontos de acumulação

No meu caso, eu preciso saber qual é o circulo que teve a maior acumulação, pois esse é o único circulo que me interessa dentre todos gerados!

Comment: Cara, isso já é implementado na própria função e ela vai retornar os círculos mais evidentes. Se você quiser, você pode definir qual o tamanho do raio do círculo que quer encontrar, ou pode mostrar o círculo que estiver em uma certa vizinhança de píxels.

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124576/73

Answer (score 2):

Muito tempo depois descobri que o vetor de círculos retornado vem ordenado de acordo com os que obtiveram maior votação, sendo assim o círculo do índice 0 é o melhor círculo dentre todos.

```
    Mat out;
    vector<Vec3f> circles
    houghCirclesHoughCircles(inputImg, circles, method, dp, minDist, param1, param2, minRadius, maxRadius);
    ///desenhando circulo mais votado em uma imagem de mesmo tamanho da imagem original
    if (!circles.empty()) {
        Point center(circles[0][0], circles[0][1]);
        int raio = circles[0][2];
        out = Mat::zeros(inputImg.size(), inputImg.type());
        circle(out, center, raio, FScalar(0, 0, 255), -1);
    }
    return out;
```