# Encontrar o centro de cada circulo na imagem

Tags: java, processamento-de-imagens

Tenho essa imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e queria pegar o x e o y do centro de cada circulo. Já tentei de várias maneiras, mas em nenhuma tive sucesso. Minha pergunta é se existe alguma lib java para fazer isso ou algum algoritmo específico, se sim por favor me indique.

Comment: Seu problema é interessante, você pode utilizar esta técnica http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105891/ajuda-processamento-de-imagem-remo%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-fundo e depois percorrer os pixels da imagem para encontrar apenas o pixel da cor dos circulos. Depois encontra a fórmula matemática para encontrar o centro. O que estou passando é muito superficial, mas é uma ideia de início

Comment: mas não adianta eu mudar a cor de fundo. Vou ficar com o mesmo problema com cores diferentes

Comment: Então desta forma você vai precisar de pontos (pixels) com coordenadas x e y que estejam na boda do circulo, estes links podem te ajudar, experimenta dar uma olhada http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103405/what-is-the-algorithm-for-finding-the-center-of-a-circle-from-three-points e http://paulbourke.net/geometry/circlesphere/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A resposta que você já tem é muito boa e fornece um algoritmo simples e muito eficiente *para a imagem de exemplo* fornecida. Entretanto, ele pode não funcionar bem para imagens mais complexas, contendo, por exemplo, ruído ou círculos sobrepostos ou incompletos (nos cantos da imagem). Como você não forneceu detalhes do seu domínio de problema, talvez essas variações possam ocorrer.

Nesse sentido, uma alternativa muito bacana é a [Transformada de Hough](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformada_de_Hough). Esse algoritmo permite encontrar em uma imagem *qualquer tipo de forma* que seja parametrizável por meio de uma equação matemática (tais como retas, círculos, elípses, etc).

### Princípio Matemático

O princípio matemático desse algoritmo é facilmente explicado considerando o exemplo mais simples: a identificação de retas em uma imagem. Considere os gráficos abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Suponha que uma imagem contém um conjunto de pontos que, se ligados, traçam uma reta (imagem da esquerda). A equação geral de uma reta é [image: equação da reta]. Assim, em um ponto qualquer da imagem, de coordenadas [image: coordenadas], há infinita retas que passam por ele (as retas mais claras na imagem): basta variar os *parâmetros* [image: m] (a inclinação da reta) e [image: n] (a altura que ela corta no eixo [image: y]) para os valores [image: coordenadas] fixos. Naturalmente, isso vale para qualquer outro ponto. E como se pode perceber pelo desenho da esquerda, há apenas uma reta que passa por todos os pontos (a reta mais escura na imagem). Isso significa que para todos esses pontos, a equação dessa reta específica *tem o mesmo valor* de [image: m] e [image: n].

Ao invés de representar cada ponto no espaço [image: espaço xy], nós os representarmos no espaço [image: espaço mn] (também chamado de espaço paramétrico, ilustrado na figura da direita). Nesse espaço, um ponto do espaço original agora é descrito por uma reta (devido ao ajuste na equação para considerar os parâmetros como variáveis) com todas as combinações de valores [image: m] e [image: n] que, lembre-se, descrevem todas as retas possíveis que passam naquele ponto no espaço original [image: espaço xy]. Desse modo, quando existe uma reta que liga todos os pontos no espaço original, as retas no espaço de parâmetro que descrevem cada um dos pontos coincidem em um local exato: nos valores dos parâmetros [image: m] e [image: n] que justamente satisfazem a equação da reta no espaço original.

Assim, o algoritmo simplesmente trabalha no espaço paramétrico e vai testando, ponto a ponto e para cada possível valor de [image: m] e [image: n], onde se encontram esses cruzamentos. Ele faz isso construindo uma matriz z-dimensional (vide figura abaixo) onde `z` é o número de parâmetros na equação representativa da forma que se busca. Essa matriz armazena "contagens" de ocorrências dos valores dos parâmetros (tanto que é comumente chamada de matriz de *acumuladores*) em intervalos discretos. Por exemplo, no caso da equação da reta anterior, a matriz é a seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os valores dessa matriz são inicializados para `0` e conforme o algoritmo é executado eles são incrementados toda vez que um ponto qualquer da imagem original tiver uma reta com parâmetros [image: m] e [image: n] no intervalo utilizado. No final, basta escolher o par de parâmetros com mais "votos" (com maior acumulador). Ele indicará a melhor reta estimada que passa por todos os pontos analisados.

> Eu espero que essa explicação seja suficiente. Mas se precisar de uma
>   explicação passo-a-passo, [esse vídeo (em inglês)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uDB2qGqnQ1g) pode ser de muita
>   ajuda.

É mais comum utilizar na detecção de retas a representação da equação na forma polar ([image: equação polar], em que [image: rho] representa o vetor normal à reta e [image: theta] é o ângulo desse vetor em relação ao eixo horizontal), porque assim se evita ter de tratar casos em que o valor do parâmetro [image: n] é infinito (a reta está inclinada em 90º).

No caso da detecção de círculos (o seu interesse), utiliza-se comumente [a equação da circunferência](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circunfer%C3%AAncia#Equa.C3.A7.C3.B5es) na forma paramétrica (onde [image: ab] são as coordenadas do centro do círculo, [image: r] é seu raio e [image: theta] é o ângulo em relação ao eixo horizontal):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse algoritmo tem como vantagens ser razoavelmente simples e fácil de implementar, ser robusto à ruído (pois o ruído gera menos "votos"/acumuladores) e a dados parciais (os dados de apenas parte de um círculo, por exemplo, ainda assim geram bastante acumuladores para um mesmo conjunto de parâmetros). A principal desvantagem é que ele se torna computacionalmente custoso conforme o número de parâmetros cresce. No exemplo da reta a matriz era bidimensional pois utilizava-se 2 parâmetros. No caso do círculo são 3, fazendo com que agora tenhamos uma matriz tridimensional para manipular.

### Implementação

Eu construí um código de exemplo, da forma mais simples e didática possível. Ele segue abaixo. Vale notar o seguinte:

1 - Ele foi feito pensando mesmo na didática. Então não está tão otimizado quanto poderia. Por exemplo, o espaço de armazenamento da matriz de acumuladores poderia ser diminuido conforme a configuração de raio mínimo e máximo, e eu simplesmente aloco a área máxima mesmo que não a utilize completamente. Além disso, a ordenação dos círculos encontrados e a eliminação de círculos semelhantes foi feita de forma bem simples e direta, com mais de uma varredura da matriz de acumuladores. Certamente há formas melhor de fazer isso.

2 - A definição dos limites de parâmetros foi feita de forma empírica. Por exemplo, no caso do ângulo eu simplesmente dividi a matriz em 360 graus, em intervalos de 1 grau. E no caso do raio, ele vai do mínimo configurado ao máximo calculado (a metade da diagonal da imagem), também em intervalos de 1 pixel. Essa não é necessariamente a forma correta de se fazer. Analisando código existente, percebe-se que é mais comum fazer o intervalo angular ser 1/8 do menor raio (admito que não sei exatamente a razão disso, mas certamente tem a ver com desempenho de armazenamento vs desempenho de resultado de detecção).

3 - Apesar de esse ser um algoritmo simples e fácil de implementar, na prática *não vale a pena* reimplementá-lo. Há inúmeras implementações disponíveis, e a mais indicada [é a do OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html) - que também [pode ser utilizado em Java](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv).

Eis o código:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Teste {

    /**
     * Inner class para representação de círculos. 
     */
    public static class Circle {
        /** Coordenada x do centro do círculo. */
        public int x;

        /** Coordenada y do centro do círculo. */
        public int y;

        /** Raio do círculo em pixels. */
        public int r;

        /**
         * Construtor da classe.
         * @param x Coordenada x do centro do círculo.
         * @param y Coordenada y do centro do círculo.
         * @param r Raio do círculo em pixels.
         */
        public Circle(int x, int y, int r) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.r = r;
        }

        /**
         * Verifica se os círculos são similares segundo um limiar.
         * @param oOther Instância do outro círculo para comparação.
         * @param iThreshold Inteiro com o limiar para comparação.
         * @return Verdadeiro se os círculos são similares segundo
         * o limiar dado, falso caso contrário.
         */
        public boolean similarTo(Circle oOther, int iThreshold) {
            return Math.abs(oOther.x - x) <= iThreshold &&
                   Math.abs(oOther.y - y) <= iThreshold &&
                   Math.abs(oOther.r - r) <= iThreshold;
        }
    };

    /**
     * Cria uma janela para exibição da imagem dada.
     * @param oImage Objeto BufferedImage com a imagem a ser exibida.
     * @param sTitle String com o título da janela.
     * @return Instância de JFrame com a janela criada.
     */
    private static JFrame showImage(Image oImage, String sTitle) {
        JFrame oWindow = new JFrame();
        JPanel oPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JLabel oWidget = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(oImage));
        oPanel.add(oWidget);
        oWindow.add(oPanel);
        oWindow.setVisible(true);
        oWindow.setTitle(sTitle);
        oWindow.pack();
        oWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        return oWindow;
    }

    /** Máscara para cálculo do gradiente por convolução no eixo X. */
    private static int[][] SOBEL_X = {
                                        { -1, 0, +1 },
                                        { -2, 0, +2 },
                                        { -1, 0, +1 },
                                     };

    /** Máscara para cálculo do gradiente por convolução no eixo Y. */
    private static int[][] SOBEL_Y = {
                                        { +1, +2, +1 },
                                        {  0,  0,  0 },
                                        { -1, -2, -1 },
                                     }; 

    /**
     * Processa a imagem (por convolução) para extração das bordas.
     * @param oImage BufferedImage com a instância da imagem original.
     * @return BufferedImage com a imagem binária contendo apenas as bordas (em
     * branco) sobre o fundo (em preto).
     */
    private static BufferedImage getEdges(BufferedImage oImage) {
        BufferedImage oRet = new BufferedImage(oImage.getWidth(), oImage.getHeight(), oImage.getType());

        // Percorre a imagem para fazer a convolução
        for(int x = 0; x < oImage.getWidth(); x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < oImage.getHeight(); y++) {

                // Calcula as somas ponderadas pelas máscaras no pixel atual
                int iSumX = 0, iSumY = 0;               
                for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                        int xl = x + (i - 1);
                        int yl = y + (j - 1);

                        int iValue;
                        if(xl >= 0 && xl < oImage.getWidth() && yl >= 0 && yl < oImage.getHeight()) {
                            Color oColor = new Color(oImage.getRGB(xl, yl));
                            iValue = (int) Math.ceil((0.21 * oColor.getRed() + 0.72 * oColor.getGreen()  + 0.07 * oColor.getBlue()));
                        }
                        else { // Considera pixels fora da imagem com o mesmo valor do pixel atual
                            Color oColor = new Color(oImage.getRGB(x, y));
                            iValue = (int) Math.ceil((0.21 * oColor.getRed() + 0.72 * oColor.getGreen()  + 0.07 * oColor.getBlue()));
                        }

                        iSumX += iValue * SOBEL_X[i][j];
                        iSumY += iValue * SOBEL_Y[i][j];
                    }
                }

                // Calcula a magnitude do gradiente no pixel e atualiza a imagem de retorno
                int iMag = (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(iSumX, 2) + Math.pow(iSumY, 2)));
                oRet.setRGB(x, y, iMag > 254 ? Color.WHITE.getRGB() : Color.BLACK.getRGB());
            }
        }

        return oRet;
    }

    /**
     * Cria uma tabela de referência para os cálculos envolvendo seno e cosseno,
     * como forma de otimizar o desempenho do algoritmo.
     * @param iMaxRadius Inteiro com o maior raio buscado (utilizado na definição
     * do tamanho da estrutura de dados).
     * @return Matriz de 3 dimensões com os dados do seno e cosseno dos diferentes
     * ângulos possíveis, já multiplicados pelos valores de raio possíveis.
     */
    private static int[][][] buildLookupTable(int iMaxRadius) {
        // A tabela tem espaço para 2 valores (do seno e do cosseno), n raios
        // (sendo n a metade da diagonal da imagem = raio do maior círculo
        // possível) e 360 graus (theta).
        int aTable[][][] = new int[2][iMaxRadius + 1][361];

        for(int iRadius = 0; iRadius <= iMaxRadius; iRadius++) {
            for(int iAngle = 0; iAngle <= 360; iAngle++) {

                double dRad = Math.PI * iAngle / 180; // ângulo em radianos
                int iCos = (int) (iRadius * Math.cos(dRad));
                int iSin = (int) (iRadius * Math.sin(dRad));

                aTable[0][iRadius][iAngle] = iSin;
                aTable[1][iRadius][iAngle] = iCos;
            }
        }

        return aTable;
    }

    /**
     * Processa a imagem de bordas (pela transformada de Hough de círculos) para extração
     * dos círculos.
     * @param oImage BufferedImage com a instância da imagem binária com as bordas.
     * @param iMinRadius Inteiro com o menor raio a ser procurado.
     * @param iMaxRadius Inteiro com o maior raio a ser procurado.
     * @param iMaxCircles Inteiro com o número máximo de círculos a ser devolvido.
     * @return 
     */
    private static Circle[] getCircles(BufferedImage oImage, int iMinRadius, int iMaxRadius, int iMaxCircles) {

        // Constroi a tabela de lookup (pra agilizar os cálculos)
        int aTable[][][] = buildLookupTable(iMaxRadius);

        // Calcula os acumuladores na imagem, segundo a equação paramétrica do círculo
        int aAcc[][][] = new int[oImage.getWidth()][oImage.getHeight()][iMaxRadius+1];

        for(int x = 0; x < oImage.getWidth(); x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < oImage.getHeight(); y++) {

                // Ignora pixels que não contêm bordas
                if(oImage.getRGB(x, y) == Color.BLACK.getRGB())
                    continue;

                for(int iRadius = iMinRadius; iRadius <= iMaxRadius; iRadius++) {
                    for(int iAngle = 0; iAngle <= 360; iAngle++) {

                        int a = x + aTable[1][iRadius][iAngle];
                        int b = y + aTable[0][iRadius][iAngle];

                        if(a >= 0 && a < oImage.getWidth() && b >= 0 && b < oImage.getHeight())
                            aAcc[a][b][iRadius]++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Cria estrutura ordenada pelos acumuladores
        Map<Integer, Circle> mAcc = new TreeMap<Integer, Circle>(new Comparator<Integer>() 
        {
            @Override
            public int compare(Integer i, Integer j) {                
                return j.compareTo(i);
             }
        });

        for(int a = 0; a < aAcc.length; a++) {
            for(int b = 0; b < aAcc[a].length; b++) {
                for(int r = 0; r < aAcc[a][b].length; r++) {
                    int iAcc = aAcc[a][b][r];
                    mAcc.put(iAcc, new Circle(a, b, r));
                }
            }
        }

        // Move os dados para um array, já removendo as duplicidades
        ArrayList<Circle> aRet = new ArrayList<Circle>();
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Circle> oCur: mAcc.entrySet()) {

            // Procura no ArrayList por um círculo parecido
            // Se existir, ignora. Caso contrário, adiciona.
            boolean bExist = false;
            for(Circle oExist: aRet) {
                if(oCur.getValue().similarTo(oExist, 10))
                {
                    bExist = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(!bExist)
                aRet.add(oCur.getValue());
        }

        // Devolve o número de círculos desejado
        return aRet.subList(0, iMaxCircles).toArray(new Circle[0]);     
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        // Carrega a imagem original
        BufferedImage oImage = null;
        try {
            URL oURL = new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWgw0.png");
            oImage = ImageIO.read(oURL);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Oops! Não foi possível carregar a imagem.");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        // Exibe a imagem original
        JFrame oSource = showImage(oImage, "Imagem original");

        // Processa a imagem original para detecção das bordas
        BufferedImage oEdges = getEdges(oImage);

        // Exibe a imagem com as bordas detectadas
        JFrame oTarget = showImage(oEdges, "Imagem com as bordas");
        oTarget.setLocation(oSource.getLocation().x + oSource.getWidth(), oSource.getLocation().y);

        // Aplica a transformada de Hough para o círculo
        int iMinRadius = 10;
        int iMaxRadius = (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(oImage.getWidth(), 2) + Math.pow(oImage.getHeight(), 2)) / 2);
        int iMaxCircles = 4;
        Circle[] aCircles = getCircles(oEdges, iMinRadius, iMaxRadius, iMaxCircles);

        // Desenha os círculos na imagem original
        Graphics2D g = oImage.createGraphics();
        g.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));
        for(int i = 0; i < aCircles.length; i++) {
            Circle oCircle = aCircles[i];
            g.drawLine(oCircle.x-5, oCircle.y, oCircle.x+5, oCircle.y);
            g.drawLine(oCircle.x, oCircle.y-5, oCircle.x, oCircle.y+5);
            g.drawOval(oCircle.x - oCircle.r, oCircle.y - oCircle.r, 2 * oCircle.r, 2 * oCircle.r);
        }
        g.dispose();

        // Exibe a imagem com as anotações dos círculos encontrados
        JFrame oFinal = showImage(oImage, "Imagem original anotada");
        oFinal.setLocation(oTarget.getLocation().x + oTarget.getWidth(), oTarget.getLocation().y);
    }

}
```

### Como o código funciona

O primeiro passo é limitar os dados a serem processados. Se a Transformada de Hough fosse aplicada sobre todos os pixels da imagem original, ia demorar demais e potencialmente gerar muita confusão (muitos acumuladores parecidos). Assim, primeiramente eu produzo uma imagem binária (contendo só cor preta e branca) apenas com as bordas encontradas na imagem. O melhor modo de fazer isso é aplicar o [filtro Sobel](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filtro_Sobel) por meio de [convolução](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolu%C3%A7%C3%A3o) no domínio espacial seguido de uma [limiarização](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thresholding_(image_processing)) simples (não vou explicar esse processo em detalhes por falta de espaço, mas leia os links da Wikipedia e analise o código pra entender).

> Note essa linha de código no método `getEdges`:
>
> ```
> oRet.setRGB(x, y, iMag > 254 ? Color.WHITE.getRGB() : Color.BLACK.getRGB());
> ```
>
> O valor `254` ali é o limiar utilizado para limiarização. Ou seja, eu
>   praticamente ignoro (faço ser igual à cor preta) qualquer valor de
>   magnitude do gradiente que seja menor ou igual a 254. Isso deixa as bordas mais
>   finas, e reduz informação (pixels de borda) na imagem resultante. Vc pode/deve
>   ajustar esse limiar conforme o seu domínio de problema.

Então, a transformada de Hough é aplicada **apenas aos pixels em branco** na imagem de bordas (ou seja, apenas aos pixels de borda). Essa abordagem é muito comum na literatura, pois esses são os pixels essenciais para a detecção de formas. :)

O resultado da execução desse código para a sua imagem de exemplo (lida diretamente da sua postagem) é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu fiz uma imagem de exemplo com algumas variações que podem ser difícies de detectar no algoritmo mais simples anterior:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O resultado do código para essa imagem é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que você precisa alterar para 7 o número máximo de círculos na chamada do método `getCircles`:

```
. . .
int iMinRadius = 10;
int iMaxRadius = (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(oImage.getWidth(), 2) + Math.pow(oImage.getHeight(), 2)) / 2);
int iMaxCircles = 7; // ALTERE AQUI CONFORME O NÚMERO DE CÍRCULOS EXISTENTES
Circle[] aCircles = getCircles(oEdges, iMinRadius, iMaxRadius, iMaxCircles);
. . .
```

### Sobre a importância do processamento intermediário

O filtro de Sobel aplicado antes da transformada de Hough é fundamental para a qualidade do resultado. Outra alternativa bastante utilizada é o [filtro de Canny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector). Ainda assim, dependendo do tipo de imagem utilizada, talvez você precise *também* aplicar outros filtros para redução de rúido (usando, por exemplo, um [filtro Gaussiano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_filter) ou até mesmo filtros mais simples como [a média e mediana](http://www2.ic.uff.br/~aconci/suavizacao.pdf).

Um exemplo é para a detecção de moedas de Real na imagem abaixo. Como apenas a detecção de bordas ainda deixa muitos pixels de borda devido à textura das moedas, o resultado final (para a detecção de 10 círculos com o algoritmo acima) não é exatamente o esperado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que um círculo pequeno na moeda de 5 centavos mais à direita foi detectado com muitos acumuladores. Esse erro talvez deva-se às escolhas empíricas descritas anteriormente, e talvez pudesse ser corrigido com o ajuste do raio mínimo (se você souber de antemão o tamanho da menor moeda na imagem, por exemplo). Mas note como a imagem de bordas tem muitos detalhes. Eles fazem não somente o processamento demorar mais como também não ajudam na detecção de círculos ideais.

Comment: obrigado pela dedicação. Isso não foi só uma resposta, foi uma aula. Em alguns testes ficou um pouco lento o processo, mesmo fazendo suas indicações. Isso só ocorre quando tem vários círculos na imagem. Mas mesmo assim, sua resposta é perfeita para essa pergunta. obrigado!

Comment: Por nada. É, a lentidão é um problema sério porque o código não foi feito pensando em desempenho. rs Você pode tentar melhorar o código (sugiro medir onde demora mais) - ou use mesmo o do OpenCV. :)

Answer (score 10):

Esse problema parece ser muito difícil, mas não é.

Antes de apresentar a minha solução, aconselho que use essas bibliotecas do java:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage
```

Bem, minha solução é essa:

**Leitura:**

- Antes de tudo, crie uma matriz com as dimensões da imagem de entrada.
- Ande pixel por pixel da imagem de entrada, e coloque zeros nas coordenadas da matriz que representam o branco na foto, e uns para as que representam o vermelho. No final, você terá uma matriz binária que representa a foto, 0 == branco, 1 == vermelho.

**Processamento:**

- Ande por cada coordenada da matriz vendo se a coordenada atual é 1, se for, quer dizer que você acabou de tangenciar um circulo, ou seja, tocou no ponto "mais alto" dele(Visto de um referencial 2D), guarde essa coordenada em algum lugar. Bem, pensa comigo, se eu estou no Brasil e cavo um buraco em linha reta e perpendicular ao plano que eu estou em pé, vou sair na outra extremidade da Terra(Tókio?), certo? Se eu medir o comprimento desse "túnel", eu tenho o diâmetro da Terra(considerando a Terra um circulo perfeito), não tenho? Então, finge que o pixel que estamos parados é o Brasil e que o nosso circulo é a Terra, vamos cavar um buraco até sair dele. Como que você vai fazer isso? Faz um for ou while, e nesse loop, você vai andar só em Y, ou seja, vai andar pra "baixo", enquanto o conteúdo da coordenada atual for 1, você não chegou no Japão ainda, quando a coordenada for 0, bem vindo à Tokio, se você deu azar, vai dar de cara com Kim jong Yun na Korea do Norte, ai já era kkkk. Dentro desse Loop adicione um contador, esse contador vai ter o diâmetro do circulo quando você chegar em tókio, ou seja, sair do circulo. Se você achou o diâmetro, 99.9% do problema já está morto. Você tem o ponto de tangencia e o diâmetro, com isso, você consegue achar o centro, pois o centro vai ser = (X , coordenada Y do ponto de tangencia menos o raio).
- Agora você tem que excluir o circulo que você acabou de calcular o centro, como você faz isso? Muito tranquilo, como eu disse, achou o diâmetro já era. Você vai calcular um quadrado no qual o nosso circulo seja uma circunferência inscrita nele. Partindo do centro, você vai somar e diminuir o raio tanto em X quanto em Y, ou seja, você vai ter quatro coordenadas no final dos calculos. TODOS os pontos dentro dessa área delimitada por essas coordenadas vão ser setados pra 0, ou seja, nosso circulo foi excluído e podemos fazer tudo isso de novo para o próximo.

Sacou a ideia? Vai andando pixel a pixel até tocar o circulo, NECESSARIAMENTE o primeiro ponto que você tocar vai ser o mais "alto", ou seja, se você andar pra "baixo" vai chegar na outra extremidade percorrendo todo o diâmetro.

Abraço!

Comment: valeu cara, deu um pouco mais de trabalho, porque os círculos não eram perfeitos, mas com essa ideia deu certo.

Answer (score 3):

Acho que tudo é simples, muita complicação!!

```
//************************************************************
//* (hBitmap, x, y, Width, Height)  imagem em preto e branco.
//************************************************************

HB_FUNC (BT_BITMAPBLACKONWHITE)
{ 
   HDC memDC;
   HBITMAP hBitmap;
   register INT x, y;
   INT x1, y1, Width, Height, c;
   COLORREF nCor;

   hBitmap  = (HBITMAP)  hb_parnl (1);
   x1       = (INT)      hb_parnl (2);
   y1       = (INT)      hb_parnl (3);
   Width    = (INT)      hb_parnl (4);
   Height   = (INT)      hb_parnl (5);

   memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);     
   SelectObject(memDC, hBitmap);

   for (y = y1; y < (y1 + Height); y++)
   {
     for (x = x1; x < (x1 + Width); x++)
     { 

       nCor = GetPixel(memDC, x, y);       

       if (nCor < RGB(50,50,50))
       {
         SetPixel(memDC, x, y, RGB(255,255,255));    
       }
       else if (nCor > RGB(60,60,60) & nCor <= RGB(255,255,255))
       {
         SetPixel(memDC, x, y, RGB(0,0,0));    
       }       
       else
         SetPixel(memDC, x, y, RGB(255,255,255));                        
     }
   }   

   DeleteDC(memDC);
}
```

**código completo em C.**

Sem complicações e cálculos. Lembre-se teoria é uma coisa pratica é outra.

[image: Imagem em preto e branco com 0 e 1]

Comment: Não postei o código completo. te explico!.faço um loop pegando os pixel, depois comparo eles entre eles mesmos, o pixel que não estiver dentro de um valor RGB, é alterado para a cor que eu quiser, transfor. uma imagem complexa em preto e branco. existe outro loop que escreve em preto e branco. manipular cada pixel.Estou estud. sobre reconhec.facial, estou desenv. o meu próprio código. e vc não vai acreditar a linguagem é CA-Clipper, C, e Harbour Minigui.PS:vc pegar pixel por pixel funciona mais fica muito lento, então vc deve utilizar step, fazendo com que a leitura e escrita fique mais rápido

Comment: Como posso colocar exemplos, coloquei minha imagem em 0 e 1. onde posso colocar o executável, para que execute, para ver o resultado. me de umas dicas, sou novo neste site!!! Executável vacinado e pequeno. Windows 32 bits.